# Cannot use two instances of ezinearticles author widgets

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I write under mine as well as a pen-name for ezinearticles.com. They provide an author's widget for your sites, and send a code (the author's number is different). Unfortunately their policy does not allow clubbing of both names, and hence I have to use two separate widgets.

I tried:

1. Putting both codes in one text box widget (sidebar), and
2. Putting the code in different text box widgets (sidebar)
3. Put one code in text box (sidebar) and other in footer section

But the result is: *Only the top text-box's widget code works.*

Any idea what needs to be done?

```
 <!-- Place this tag where you want the widget to render -->
<div id="ezinearticles-widget"></div>

<!-- Place this script before the closing </body> tag -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ezinearticles.com/js/widget.v2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
EzineArticlesWidget({
    "id": "ezinearticles-widget",
    "author": XXXXXX,
    "bio": 1,
    "category": null,
    "articles": 3,
    "width": 250,
    "height": 150,
    "theme": {
        "shell": {
            "background": "#2F83C4",
            "text": "#ffffff"
        },
        "article": {
            "background": "#ffffff",
            "text": "#333333"
        },
        "links": "#215F8F"
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you link or post the relevant sections of what you have tried? Have you given the `div`s different `id`s?

Comment: I have not tried that. Okay, I will look up on google and try what you say.

Answer (score 0):

You should create 2 `div` elements with different `id`s,

```
<div id="ezinearticles-widget-1"></div>
<div id="ezinearticles-widget-2"></div>
```

and refer to them in your `<script>`:

```
EzineArticlesWidget({
    "id": "ezinearticles-widget-1",
    "author": 12345,
    "bio": 1,
    //...
});

EzineArticlesWidget({
    "id": "ezinearticles-widget-2",
    "author": 1234,
    "bio": 1,
    //...
});
```

I have created a simple **demo** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/PKcZ5/).

Answer (score 0):

Your example works, but not for me. I AM TOO DUMB. I tried many variations, but can't understand how to rewrite the code, especially the "scripts".

1. I did name the divs 1 and 2,
2. I tried putting the entire code (for both) under single script tag
3. I also tried putting both the divs, on top, one below the other
   `<div id="ezinearticles-widget-1"></div>
   <div id="ezinearticles-widget-2"></div>`
   and renamed the ids in the code

But the only change that happens is: the whole widget goes away and plain english text appears.

Your page uses some kind of javascript compiler. I can follow if you put the code in plain text.

I even tried putting them in different Textbox widgets, putting the ids 1 & 2, but the widget appearance goes away and plain text results.

I am not a programmer, yet feel it has something to do with the "scripts", either they need be nested or put in some order ---> which I am not able to grab.

SORRY FOR WASTING YOUR TIME. I am really dumb!

Comment: I got it done (but I don't know how). I added a form widget and suddenly my both ezinearticles widgets appeared! ALL CREDIT TO YOU. I did create the divs as you noted, and somehow Wordpress behaved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I got it done (but don't know what triggered this!)

I added a Forms widget below and suddenly everything fell in place. Suddenly, I saw both widgets. I did create the div ids you suggested, and all the thanks to you.

I wanted to send a PM, but don't know how to. I visited your profile ... but failed